# jquery fade in for multiple divs

Tags: jquery, fadein

I have multiple images loaded from my database, and at the bottom of each image I have a share button ... When the share button is clicked a new div is appear with different share options.

My problem is when I press the share button ... the hidden div is appear for all the images on the page and I want to appear only for one image not for all.

This is what I have until now:

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>"><img class="img-box" src="/images/<?php echo $img; ?>.jpg"></a>
    <div class="share-holder" name="<?php echo $img_id; ?>">share</div>
    <div class="share-fadein"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.share-fadein{
    width:210px;
    height:40px;
    background-color:#eee ;
    display:none;
}
```

SCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".share-holder").click(function(){
        $(".share-fadein").fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Thank you

Comment: Use the `this` pointer in the click callback instead of a classname

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this way: http://jsfiddle.net/9Wsfc/

```
$(".share-holder").click(function(){
    $(this).next(".share-fadein").fadeIn();
});     //--^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-------this will only fadesin the ".share-fadein"
```

Comment: i see this is working on jsfiddle .... probably something is in conflict in my code ... because for me is not working ...i will create a new page just for this  for testing ... and i will come back to give the votes for this answers ...thank you

Comment: I dont know you are attaching the jquery before this script or not.

Comment: my problem was the jquery masonry plugin, it was a conflict ...now i fix it ...thank you all for the answers

Answer (score 1):

Change your JS to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".share-holder").click(function(){
   $(this).next().fadeIn();
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".share-holder").click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.share-fadein').fadeIn();
 });
});
```

Get the closest `.share-fadein` to the clicked `.share-holder`.

See [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) jQuery.

Comment: Please add some explanatory text to make this a useful answer - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If using jQuery 1.4.3+ better use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(this).delegate(".share-holder", "click", function() {
    $(this).next().fadeIn();
  });
});
```

[Delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) is better because instead of "click" listeners for each element you have 1 listener - so the memory usage is much lower.

Comment: Johan, you're right, but we're using jQuery 1.6.2 in our project, so I got used to delegate(). :))